# Disabled Google play services

Tags: google-play-services, tablet-apps

On android tablet I seemed to  have disabled my Google play services  some how. I'm wondering, can any one simple  explain how one fixes this. I'm hoping that it's fixable and that didn't  mess things up to bad someone. Help please, Thank you.

Comment: Can you not enable it from the same location you disabled it?

Comment: Down voter, care to explain?

Answer (score -1):

Go to *Settings* → *App manager* → *All apps* → *Google play service* → Enable it.